# probability distribution of kth greatest number when 6 numbers are picked out of 45 numbers

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose there are 45 numbered balls from 1 to 45, equally likely to be picked. Then 6 balls are picked at once. These balls are ordered in ascending order.

What would be the probability distribution of $k$th greatest ball?

Comment: To be clear: you are asking for the distribution of the $k^{th}$ highest choice out of $6$, right?

Comment: About problem statement: We should suppose that under no additional information, guess must be the most probable value of ball number, and then find probability that guess is correct? Or should we suppose that guess is uniformly random number from 1 to 45 and find probability of its correctness?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu my intention was probability of most probable value of ball number

Comment: So, first start with the max.  Do you know how to get the distribution of the max?  The usual is to compute $P(M≤k)$ and then take differences.  The broader problem goes the same way.

Comment: In the first position, you can have any ball numbered from $1$ to $40$, in second location $2$ to $41$ and so on. Now take first position as an example, is any number more likely to occur than others in random pick of $6$ numbers and placing them in ascending order?

Comment: Think order statistics deal with this